# Is there a way to treat 0 as value in integer field, not a null in x++?

Tags: integer, x++

I'm importing data from excel to my journal and I have temperature field... Some temperatures have 0 value, but when I import it to my journal and validate that journal, it says temperature field is empty. Is there a way to let the system understand that I imported 0 as value, not as null on validation??

EDIT:

I changed show zero 'no' on forms grid. It removes default zeros, but sadly it also removes my imported 0 temperature values....
I found control for that field -

```
if( !table.temperature)
            {
                ret = checkFailed(strFmt("label", fieldId2PName(table.TableId, fieldNum(table, temperature))));
            }
```

The problem is, it sees 0 as empty field...

Comment: I tryed to enable and disable it, but field didnt show anything different. I tryed to even make new row in my journal to check if it shows zero in default and in both cases it showed 0...

Comment: Sounds like the temperature field is validated as mandatory while it should not be...

Comment: I forgot about mandatory... i will try it in a moment...

Comment: i checked it doesnt have mandatory...

Comment: There are no null values in Dynamics AX/365FO tables (btw. which version are you on?). If your Excel file has no or 0 value for temperature and assuming your temperature field is an integer or real field, it will have value 0. 

Could you provide more details on how your journal table and the temperature field is set up (properties, validate methods, ...)? Also add the exact error or warning message you receive. Please [edit] your question and add the information there instead of answering in a comment. This will increase your chances of receiving an answer.

Comment: In excel that field has General format. In D365 on my table that field is integer. And yes, i have many values as 0 in excel, because temperature can be 0, but my journal thinks that its null value. when i import. This is error message - ```Field 'Min storage temperature' must be filled in.```. Temperature field has only label, help text, auto decleration and edt. This error message reminds me mandatory, but i did some research on fields, but temperature doesnt have it...

Answer (score 1):

From your edit and comments, I gather that you want to differentiate between the default 0 value in the temperature field and the 0 value imported from Excel.

As I mentioned in the comments, there are no null values in Dynamics AX/365FO tables, so bad news, you can't differentiate between those two "types" of 0 values with the temperature field on its own.

### Option 1: add a boolean field

One option is to add another field of type boolean, e.g. named `hasTemperature`. When importing temperature values from Excel, you need to add logic to set this field to true.
Then, in the code snippet from your question, you can check this field, e.g. like this:

```
if (table.hasTemperature == false)
{
    ret = checkFailed(strFmt("Field '%1' must be filled in.", fieldId2PName(table.TableId, fieldNum(table, temperature))));
}
```

Note that when data in table is entered not only by Excel import, but also by other means, you also need to add logic that sets `hasTemperature` accordingly.

### Option 2: define your own "null" value

If you don't like the idea of adding another field, you could also find a temperature value that cannot exist in your data (e.g. -4711 would be far below the [absolute zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero) temperature in both Celsius and Fahrenheit) and consider this your default "null" value. Then in the `init` method of your table, set the temperature field to that value. Make sure to document this [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) thoroughly in your code for other developers. Make also sure to call the `init` method during Excel import.

You can then rewrite your code snippet as follows:

```
if (table.temperature == -4711)
{
    ret = checkFailed(strFmt("Field '%1' must be filled in.", fieldId2PName(table.TableId, fieldNum(table, temperature))));
}
```

I would recommend that you add a static method to your table that just returns this magic number and has a meaningful name (e.g. `defaultNullTemperature`). Then use this method in your code whenever you need this magic number.